# Should I connect separate retrofit ground line to existing EGC wiring?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding

Location: California; house was built in 1950s and originally wired 2-wire, no ground for standard outlets. In late 1960s, some circuits were added, including grounded outlets in the unfinished garage.

I am adding a bare armored ground wire running from panel in garage to attic of house to retrofit ground to a number of existing outlets in the house. It will pass near a circuit extension added on to the existing grounded garage outlet circuit.  Should I bond the bare armored ground wire to the metal junction box of the added grounded circuit, creating in effect an EGC loop? Or does that not matter?

Comment: What is a "bare armored wire"? I would think that "bare" means nothing around the copper, while "armored" screams "flexible metal housing" to me. I'm honestly confused...

Comment: @FreeMan "Bare armored ground wire" is essentially a bare copper larger-diameter wire (e.g. 8 ga) inside flexible metal conduit (3/8 inch trade size iirc).  The armor gives it a bit of protection and makes it easy to secure/support without worrying about damaging the bare copper ground conductor itself. Technically probably called something like 4/1 AC in stores.

Comment: Here's one manufacturer's description: "4-Gauge Bare Armored Ground Cable protects the solid copper ground wire with flexible, interlocking galvanized steel armor. UL listed for through-wall penetrations. Designed for use with commercial, industrial and multi-residential branch circuits and feeder wiring. "

Comment: Interesting, it is exactly as it sounds, thanks! I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EGCs, loops and crossing circuits does not matter.

To retrofit a ground you need to follow the rules in 250.130(C), which are fairly liberal about where you can tie in a ground.  Generally:

- To any junction box with a sufficiently large ground going back to the panel
- To any junction box with EMT, IMC or RMC metal conduit (which qualifies as a ground path) back to the panel
- To the same panel the circuit comes out of
- To the Grounding Electrode Conductor (bare copper wire between service panel and ground rods). Use a split bolt to clamp onto this; DO NOT cut and splice!

Comment: If I am using a split bolt to clamp onto the GEC (bare wire to bare wire), can I skip the whole cambric/rubber splicing tape/electrical tape wrapping of the split bolt and leave it naked?

Comment: @Armand -- yeah, naked connectors for bare wire to bare wire connections are fine